# Microsoft Teams Webhook - Use IP address as target's actions

Tags: microsoft-teams

In Microsoft Teams, I create interactive cards with webhooks, as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using
But for each buttons of the interactive card, I would like to use IP address as target's actions.

```
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "test",
    "themeColor": "F27C54",
    "title": "test",
    "potentialAction": [
        {
            "@type": "OpenUri",
            "name": "Learn More",
            "targets": [{
                "os": "default",
                "uri": "https://learn.microsoft.com/outlook/actionable-messages"
            }]
        }, 
        {
            "@type": "OpenUri",
            "name": "Learn More 2",
            "targets": [{
                "os": "default",
                "uri": "http://142.250.201.163"
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this JSON code, the two actions properly create the interactive with two buttons in the correct channel in Microsoft Teams. The two buttons are both clickable. But while the first button open a web browser with the URL https://learn.microsoft.com/outlook/actionable-messages , the second button open a web browser with the URL https://teams.microsoft.com/null.

Any solutions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you facing this issue from teams web client or desktop client?

Comment: Desktop client.

Comment: Same error on web client.

Comment: Hi @Arnaud Schneider - I am able to repro the issue and we have raised a bug for this and concerned team is working on it.

Comment: Good news ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Update: This issue has been fixed and the fix is rolling in the internal rings. We have verified that internally and I will keep you updated once it will available publicly. Currently we don’t have any ETA to share.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the http URL in the second button. Can you try using https

http URLs are not rendered due to security reasons.

Comment: You should also need to have a valid SSL certificate available for https url.
Try using https://ngrok.com/ for testing local urls

Comment: OK, but I checked with an http:// URL and it is reachable.